# PyCharm performance better than CMD python command

Tags: python, pycharm

I am developing a python script for serial communications.

I'm developing it in pyCharm 4.5, python27 and windows and I just realised that when I execute it on pyCharm it works faster than whe I use the command

```
python main.py or python -u main.py
```

It seems like the script runs faster on pyCharm than in a batchfile like this:

C:\Python27\python.exe .\main.py

There is any option to configure the execution faster? [at the same speed that pyCharm]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: likely due to pyCharm already having an open interpreter. Cmd must start it's own interpreter, which incurs a given overhead. Imagine the time to open pyCharm as being part of your execution time...

Comment: The fact is that I open the wxPython application and it runs (in this part is not a problem de performance), but after this when I run the communications script i gets slower than doing tha same with pyCharm.

Comment: For wxPython, should you be using `pythonw.exe`?  (Can't see it making that much difference though).

Comment: This maybe improves the performance, but in any case pyCharm uses python.exe. I need also to print some imformation in the console with print() function which is not available in pythonw.exe

Comment: How do you know the script runs faster? Did you measure the execution time? What exactly is faster?

Comment: We execute a communications test. With python console or py2exe generated file and it spends like 30 seconds, bute when I execute the test using pyCharm 4.5 it spends 15 seconds which is a big difference.

Is there any configuration which provoques this?