# Script performs better when run through PyCharm than when run directly in command line

Tags: python, pycharm

That very same question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654360/pycharm-performance-better-than-cmd-python-command) but got no answers.

I wrote a script that takes very long to complete, and am using a module ([tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/2.2.3/)) to give me feedback on its progress. When run on a remote environment through PyCharm, the script performance is between 800 and 1000 iterations per second, which yields an estimated total run time somewhere between 4 and 5 hours.

Problems arise when I try to run the script through a classic Linux command line, on the same remote environment. Under the same circumstances, within the same environment, using the same command, with the only difference that I typed it myself instead of having PyCharm issue it for me, the script performance drops to 200-300 iterations per second, resulting in an estimated 10-16 hours run.

In PyCharm, the run config window for my script looks like this:
[image: pycharm run config] 
As you can see, the used interpreter is located on my development server, in the virtual environment used by the whole project.
I had to hide the script name and parameters, which you may find inconvenient, but I don't believe my issue is related to the script itself or its contents anyway.

In order to run the same script through the command line, here is what I do:

- SSH to my server
- `cd` to my project folder
- activate my environment
- `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`
- run the same script with the same options

...which should actually result in the same behaviour, right? Well yes, but not at the same speed. There is this 70% performance drop that happens for reasons that I can't figure out, and which seems to be documented nowhere on the Internet.

I've also tried, in an attempt to perfectly mock what Pycharm does:

- copying the exact command output by PyCharm upon running the script, and pasting it in my terminal (to no avail)
- issuing `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` before running the script, which I knew would change nothing (it didn't)

I'm losing my mind over this. Is this the result of some shady PyCharm shenanigans?
Any kind of input related to anything PyCharm does which could even remotely speed up some aspect of a Python script execution is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open pycharm File> Setting > Project Interpreter. At top there would be a 'Project Interpreter' heading and in front of it would be an address like C/users.......  Change it to python located in appdata folder. Run the program and check runtime. This isn't the answer, this is just a test which would lead to answer.

Comment: @ObaidUrRehman unfortunately I'm not going to be able to do that... Before giving you feedback on the estimated runtime, a pre-processing step needs to take place (fetching all of a DB's contents and trim it to keep only the useful data). That requires about 95GB of memory and my personal laptop would have a seizure if I were to try and run it locally :( What metric were you trying to get?

Comment: One more here... In my case, a heavily (yet very simple code-wise) multi-processed script takes 3 seconds on Pycharm, 180 seconds on the terminal (same interpreter)

Comment: Kinda insane how this issue has been around since [at least 2015](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206604555-Python-script-runs-faster-on-PyCharm-than-Python-command-line) but there still isn't one single answer that would even begin to point out what the issue could be. You can't even be mad at Jetbrains since if it's their doing, then it's actually sweet, sort of. Still really frustrating.